# Apply function based upon column index to data frame

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to apply a certain function to groups of columns from a data frame based upon a 'design' vector containing the column indices that are part of the same experimental design 'group' (i.e. replicates). My observations are the rows, my sampling points are the columns.
The design vector designates which columns should group together:

```
designvector <- c(rep(1,2), rep(2,3), rep(3,3), rep(4,2), rep(5,2), rep(6,2), 
                       rep(7,2), rep(8,2), rep(9,2))
```

A small example of the data frame to which I want to apply the function is:

```
structure(list(`1` = c(4381L, 608L, 7648L, 458L, 350L, 203L), 
`1` = c(6450L, 1389L, 4896L, 526L, 920L, 352L), `2` = c(1966L, 
59L, 492L, 5291L, 1401L, 133L), `2` = c(6338L, 281L, 2649L, 
4718L, 1281L, 377L), `2` = c(12399L, 578L, 3094L, 1787L, 
1180L, 541L), `3` = c(9629L, 554L, 7299L, 2819L, 1314L, 497L
), `3` = c(11329L, 709L, 3720L, 2909L, 1929L, 655L), `3` = c(11319L, 
535L, 5212L, 2191L, 1239L, 633L), `4` = c(7427L, 8637L, 894L, 
2L, 782L, 120L), `4` = c(6748L, 9139L, 431L, 28L, 871L, 224L
), `5` = c(7125L, 11819L, 1728L, 9L, 607L, 313L), `5` = c(8651L, 
11022L, 442L, 96L, 728L, 249L), `6` = c(17879L, 3402L, 319L, 
6L, 1226L, 489L), `6` = c(20859L, 2648L, 463L, 10L, 1189L, 
408L), `7` = c(13457L, 1124L, 9386L, 18L, 635L, 367L), `7` = c(16292L, 
1732L, 6552L, 20L, 1022L, 431L), `8` = c(9035L, 5887L, 185L, 
11L, 550L, 1814L), `8` = c(14831L, 5833L, 570L, 8L, 1089L, 
1462L), `9` = c(22023L, 2254L, 5212L, 63L, 555L, 1254L), 
`9` = c(16887L, 2491L, 4949L, 68L, 921L, 983L)), .Names = c("1", 
"1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6", 
"7", "7", "8", "8", "9", "9"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

However, using `ddply` I get an error which I do not really understand:
 `ddply(abmat.sum,.(designvector),mean)` gives the following output:

```
designvector V1
1            1 NA
2            2 NA
3            3 NA
4            4 NA
5            5 NA
6            6 NA
7            7 NA
8            8 NA
9            9 NA
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(piece, ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(piece, ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default(piece, ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
4: In mean.default(piece, ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
5: In mean.default(piece, ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
6: In mean.default(piece, ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
7: In mean.default(piece, ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
8: In mean.default(piece, ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
9: In mean.default(piece, ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I am clueless as to what I am doing wrong here.
Any suggestions using ddply or other methods then for-looping over the dataframe are welcome.

Comment: your `designvector` is just: `rep(1:9, c(2,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2))`

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Take one whole `mean` of each of these two columns separately?

Comment: @Arun thank you for the tip on the use of `rep`, I didn't know yet this was possible. Also, I am only trying to take the mean for each row. However, the solution below by Richie Cotton fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `abmat.sum` is in the wrong form (it is "wide" rather than "long", as required by `ddply`).  Use `melt` to fix that.

```
library(reshape2)
abmat.sum_long <- melt(abmat.sum)
abmat.sum_long$variable <- as.numeric(abmat.sum_long$variable)
```

You also need to pass `summarise` to `ddply`.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(abmat.sum_long, .(variable), summarise, mean_value = mean(value))
```

Comment: Thanks. This proved to be exactly the answer I needed.